# Reverse proxy with ssh tunnels

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

Please help with the following situation:

I need to access an internal site that can be accessed only from an authenticated user&computer from the internal network. No additional software can be installed on the computer from the internal network. I was planning to use SSH tunnels as follows, because on the internal computer I can run the built-in Windows SSH client:

Internal site <-> (https) Internal computer->(SSH client connection to external SSH server)<-(SSH tunnel from my external laptop to external SSH server + browser access to internal site using SOCKS proxy)
Internal site must identify connection as originating from authenticated user&computer from the internal network. External laptop and user are not registered to internal network.
Items involved are

- Internal https site
- Internal laptop (10.x.x.x) can run Windows SSH client
- Internet accessible SSH server
- External laptop (Windows)

Is that possible to be done with SSH tunnels?
Thank you!

Comment: This sounds a lot like circumventing security controls.